# encountering an issue with FCM

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-sns

I encountering an issue with FCM. Can ASW SNS provide following information when we send push notifications?

- The count of users who have received the notification.
- The count of users who have not received the notification.
- The count of users who have opened the notification.
- The count of users who have dismissed the notification.